# How to get the records from the past 1 hour in psql

Tags: psql

```
SELECT * FROM auto_sync WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

I am trying to fetch data which get added in the past 1 hour from my query but it's throwing me an error on *Internal 1*. Thank you

Comment: You are trying to execute a MySQL SQL in Postgresql.

Comment: I was not sure about that, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
ORDER BY timestamp DESC

try this maybe? not sure if timestamp or time, try with both

Comment: This is giving me an output like this, but not with your's query.         SELECT * FROM auto_sync where time < now()-interval '1 hour';